# How to fix "format not a string literal and no format arguments" error?

Tags: c++

The below code compiles and works fine, but it fails when passing `-Wformat-security` in the compiler options.

```cpp
ACPI_STATUS
AcpiOsSignal(UINT32 function, void *info)
{
    DEBUG_FUNCTION();

    switch (function) {
        case ACPI_SIGNAL_FATAL:
#ifdef _KERNEL_MODE
            panic(info == NULL ? "AcpiOsSignal: fatal" : (const char*)info);
            break;
#endif
        case ACPI_SIGNAL_BREAKPOINT:
            if (info != NULL)
                AcpiOsPrintf("AcpiOsBreakpoint: %s ****\n", (const char*)info);
            else
                AcpiOsPrintf("At AcpiOsBreakpoint ****\n");
            break;
    }

    return AE_OK;
}
```

It fails on the closing parenthesis of this line:

```cpp
panic(info == NULL ? "AcpiOsSignal: fatal" : (const char*)info);
```

> error: format not a string literal and no format arguments

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently it does, and that was it!  I should have tried that before.  I have dont that have with direct printf types.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When `-Wformat-security` is enabled, the compiler verifies at compile-time that a format string passed to a function taking printf-style parameters is well-formed for the arguments it is given.

The error you see happens when a non-literal string is passed to the format parameter at runtime, and no other arguments are given. If the string were to contain any formatting placeholders, the function will not behave properly at runtime. The compiler can't verify that at compile-time, so it errors to warn you about that risk.

In this case, `panic()` must be accepting printf-style arguments. The fix is to pass in a format string literal using the `%s` placeholder, eg:

```cpp
panic("%s", info == NULL ? "AcpiOsSignal: fatal" : (const char*)info);
```

See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Format-Security-FAQ for more details.